# Path diagram in r

Tags: r, r-lavaan, structural-equation-model, causality, semplot

I am trying to plot a path diagram of a Structural Equation Model(SEM) in R. I was able to plot it using `semPlot::semPaths()`. The output is similar to [image] The SEM was modeled using `lavaan` package.

I want a plot similar to [image]. with estimates and p values. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion would be `lavaanPlot` (see more of it in the [author's personal website](https://www.alexlishinski.com/post/lavaanplot-0-5-1/)):

```r
library(lavaan)
library(lavaanPlot)
# path model
model <- 'mpg ~ cyl + disp + hp
          qsec ~ disp + hp + wt'

fit1 <- sem(model, data = mtcars)
labels1 <- list(mpg = "Miles Per Gallon", cyl = "Cylinders", disp = "Displacement", hp = "Horsepower", qsec = "Speed", wt = "Weight") #define labels
lavaanPlot(model = fit1, labels = labels1, coefs = TRUE, stand = TRUE, sig = 0.05) #standardized regression paths, showing only paths with p<= .05
```

[image]

Comment: When I tried your sample code in my system, it is working fine. But with my model it is giving me an error "Error in as.character.default(new("lavaan", version = "0.6.8", call = lavaan::lavaan(model = model1,  : 
  no method for coercing this S4 class to a vector".

Comment: My model, sem_protein <- sem(model1, data = data1,estimator="DWLS"). This model is working without any error.  summary(sem_protein)
lavaan 0.6-8 ended normally after 231 iterations

  Estimator                                       DWLS
  Optimization method                           NLMINB
  Number of free parameters                         48
                                                      
                                                  Used       Total
  Number of observations                        151977      224714

Comment: Just try: `lavaanPlot(model = fit_your_model)` just use this with your own model. If you want to use labels, you must define them accordingly.

Comment: That Worked.  I have many exogenous categorical variables with more than 2 categories. I replaced each of them k-1 dummy variables and got the estimates. However, in the lavaanPlot, I have k-1 rectangles for k-1 dummy variables. Since I have many variables to dummy code plot is not looking good. Is there any way to work with this?

Comment: Here is the sample code;

`WI=rep(c("WI1","WI2","WI3","WI4","WI5"),10)
ED=c(rep("ED1",15 ),
     rep("ED2",7),
     rep("ED3",8),
     rep("ED4",20))
Price=rnorm(50,70,5)
Dem=rnorm(50,120,5)
Status=round(runif(50,0,1),0)
df=data.frame(WI,ED,Price,Status,Dem)

df_1 = cbind(df, dummy.code(df$WI))
df_1 = cbind(df_1, dummy.code(df$ED))
# path model
model <- 'Price ~ WI2+WI3+WI4+WI5
          Dem ~ ED2+ED3+ED4
          Status ~ Price +Dem
          '
fit1 <- sem(model, data = df_1)
lavaanPlot(model = fit1,coefs = TRUE)`

Comment: If if solves your problem, please mark it as solved.

`lavaanPlot(model = fit1, graph_options = list(layout="dot",rankdir = "LR"), coefs=T, stand=T)`

Comment: Is there any way to subgraph few nodes and form clusters (for example, all the dummies of a categorical variable) like in DiagrammeR.

Comment: Hmmm I do not think that it is possible. But you can always ask the original author if it is possible to group particular variables. Here (https://github.com/alishinski/lavaanPlot)

Answer (score 0):

check this example, it might be helpful
https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/78926_5aa94ae32fae49f3a384ce885744ef4a.html